# Redirect www.url.com/x=y to www.url.com/file.php?x=y with htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, hyperlink

I realize this question is really poorly formed but that's why I am asking it; I wouldn't know how to type this in google.

I want to redirect:

```
www.url.com/x=2
```

to:

```
www.url.com/file.php?x=2
```

Comment: If your question is about how to google this: "mod-rewrite tutorial" and "regex syntax".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
 Redirect 301 /x=2 www.url.com/file.php?x=2
```

**EDIT**

If you need to mass-redirect a group of links you would probably need to use the RedirectMatch directive.

```
RedirectMatch ^/x=(.*)$ /file.php?x=$1
```

Comment: Alright, would 'Redirect 301 /x=2 /file.php?x=2' also work or do you need to include the entire url? I'm sorry I've never worked with htaccess before

Comment: if this answer if ok for you, don't forget to accept-it

Comment: Okay and how do I make it take the get parameter? right now it'll only redirect when x = 2 but how do I make it redirect regardless of what is behind the equals sign? (and yeah I'll accept it)